# I try to load json file then filter some data, but I failed to load it even

Tags: python, json

I'm new in learning programming, python, and in this forum as well.
I want to load one json file in VS Code and get some data from it to use it in excel.
But it just fails to load at the beginning when I write.

I wrote this code to view json file.

```
import json

with open("18july.json") as f:
jsondata = json.load(f)

print(jsondata)
```

when I run py file, it wrote in terminal

```
PS C:\Users\monst\Downloads\python files> & C:/Users/monst/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe "c:/Users/monst/Downloads/python files/tidyjson.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\monst\Downloads\python files\tidyjson.py", line 4, in <module>
    jsondata = json.load(f)
  File "C:\Users\monst\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load    
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Users\monst\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1254.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 1502: character maps to <undefined>
```

You can download my attached json and py file in the link below.
Also my VS Code screenshot when I run it.
https://filetransfer.io/data-package/64l6xzJS

Thanks for your interest.
Thank you.

Comment: `with open('18july.json', encoding='utf8') as f:`  The default encoding on Windows is not UTF-8 but the file is encoded in UTF-8.  Specify the encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution:

```py
import json
from pathlib import Path

filepath = Path("18july.json")
jsondata = json.loads(filepath.read_bytes())

print(jsondata)
```